# Apache 2.2 mod_ssl configuration Forward Secrecy/BREACH/BEAST/CRIME

Tags: tls, apache

I am looking for mod_ssl configuration which protects against common attacks like Breach, Beast and Crime. I already disabled gzip to avoid Crime but I'm unsure about the others.
RC4 should only be available to mitigate Beast.

Furthermore I am looking for a proper forward secrecy if possible.

This is a part of my current SSL vhost

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLHonorCipherOrder on

<Location />
    SetEnv no-gzip
</Location>

SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+AESGCM EDH+AESGCM EECDH -RC4 EDH -CAMELLIA -SEED !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints regarding where to find more information on SSL-setups and attack-mitigations: Ciphers depend on the OpenSSL version running on your server:

- [SSL Labs: Deploying Forward Secrecy](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2013/06/25/ssl-labs-deploying-forward-secrecy)
- [Configuring Apache, Nginx, and OpenSSL for Forward Secrecy](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2013/08/05/configuring-apache-nginx-and-openssl-for-forward-secrecy)
- [Mozilla: Security/Server Side TLS](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS)
- [SSL - Attack - mitigations](https://www.mare-system.de/guide-to-nginx-ssl-spdy-hsts/#ssl-attacks-and-mitigations)